# How to apply a component's [ngClass] to its child element

Tags: css, angular, angular-components

Is there a way to allow `ngClass` to be set on a parent element, but redirect it so the classes are actually applied to a child element?

```html
<!-- Parent Component -->
<app-progress-bar [ngClass]="someObject"><!-- Specify [ngClass] here… -->
</app-progress-bar>
```

```html
<!-- Child Component -->
<div class="progress-bar" [ngClass]="ngClass"><!-- …but it actually applies here -->
  <progress [max]="max" [attr.value]="value">
  </progress>
</div>
```

Obviously this could be done by using a custom `@Input` on the parent component, then feeding that input into the `[ngClass]` declaration in the child. Can it be done directly without an intermediary property?

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve this with the `::ng-deep` selector. The css styles will be applied on the `app-progress-bar` component but the styles will be activated on the child.

```css
:host {
  .some-style-evaluated-by-ng-class {
    ::ng-deep .progress-bar {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

[ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.